# Does every non-compact hyperbolic manifold admit compact complex submanifolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemannian-geometry

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a complete Kähler manifold with a metric of negative holomorphic sectional curvature. Does $X$ admit a proper, positive-dimensional, compact complex submanifold?

In general, it is well-known that there are compact complex manifolds which do not admit compact complex submanifolds — take a generic torus of dimension at least two, for instance. Note that the torus is not (Kobayashi) hyperbolic.

Comment: I don't know much about complex submanifolds but e.g. suppose $X$ is a complex hyperbolic manifold with infinite cyclic fundamental group. Thus the universal cover of $X$ is the complex hyperbolic space. Does $X$ contain a compact complex submanifold (of positive dimension)?

Comment: What about the open unit disk with its hyperbolic metric?

Comment: More counterexamples arise from the complex hyperbolic spaces: https://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/j.r.parker/img/NCHG.pdf

Comment: Does the title imply that $X$ should be non-compact?

Comment: Any simply connected complete Kahler manifold with negative sectional curvature has negative holomorphic sectional curvature ,and is a Stein manifold . Any complex submanifold of it has negative holomorphic sectional curvature .